# Using Custom Fields to Trigger Specific Actions on Saving a Post?

Tags: custom-field, hooks

Can custom fields be used to determine specific actions upon saving a post to the database?

Which action(s) make this possible, since adding post medata seems to always occur after saving a post and thus any plugin hooking into `wp_insert_post` is activated before the post meta data has been added to the post.

Comment: *@BjornW:* If you can give a few more details of you use case maybe I or someone else could whip up a small example to show you how.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to run the function after the post meta data has been added/updated, use:

```
add_action( 'updated_post_meta', 'my_post_meta_function' );
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's no complicated logic involved in updating the custom fields, you could derive the new values by grabbing their (changed) values from $_POST and combining these with their existing values from the database. Base your processing upon the resulting values.